# Insert or update query executed successfully but data are not persistent

Tags: sql, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I'm trying to insert or update elements in an existing Firebird database using JDBC. I access the database with the default credentials (*SYSDBA* and *masterkey*).

The request are done successfully according to JDBC, but the database is not modified (when I execute a *select* my data does not appear). I also tried to modify the database content using software like RazorSQL, the result is the same (the database is modified during the session, but if I disconnect and reconnect to the database my modifications are lost).

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you are running with `autoCommit` disabled. In that case you need to explicitly call [`commit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29) on the `Connection`. Also be aware that a transaction can only see changes from transactions that were committed before it started.

See also the *Jaybird JDBC Driver Java Programmer's Manual*, [chapter "Using transactions"](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#transactions).